# SQL Query to select a string after last delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve a String after last appearance of *~* delimiter. I have whole string like "Attachments:Attachments~Attachment" and I want to take substring after *~* characters that is output will be *Attachment*. How can be this done in SQL/Oracle select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ***[REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm)***

```
select regexp_substr('Attachments:Attachments~Attachment','[^~]+$') from dual;
```

- `[^ ]` - Used to specify a nonmatching list where you are trying to match any character except for the ones in the list.
- `+`    - Matches one or more occurrences
- `$`    - Matches the end of a string

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dde27b06d7e6126f378384e9352d34a2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `substr` and `instr` for such simple pattern matching requirements as `regexp` will be costly compared to `substr` and `instr` combination.

You can try the following:

```
substr(str,instr(str,'~',-1) + 1)
```

**Example:**

```
SQL> select substr('Attachments:Attachments~Attachment1~Attachment2',
  2                instr('Attachments:Attachments~Attachment1~Attachment2','~',-1) + 1)
  3    from dual;

SUBSTR('ATT
-----------
Attachment2

SQL>
```